# How to convert CSV data into JSON format to use inside a table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have response data in CSV format which I want to use in the table and get the row data if I click on any row of that particular row data

I try using CSVtoHtml npm but the row-clicking functionality does not work there.

**CSV:**

```
 {**CSV here**}
```

I have to make Symbol, Name, Sector, Validtill as heading and data below.

I have tried converting them in an object which came up like this but doesn't show up in the table unable to map the data:

```
CSV after converting to Objects:
    {0:...},
    {1:...},
    {2:...},
    ...,

..
```

this didn't map to the table

the code:

```
function Stocks() {
    const { readString } = usePapaParse();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [stocksData, setStocksData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(baseURL).then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data)
          readString(response.data, {
            worker: true,
            complete: (results) => {
              const obj = results.data.map((el) => {
                return { ...el };
              });
              console.log(obj, "obj");
              setStocksData(obj);
            },
          });
        });
    }, []);

  return (
    <div className="grid inline mx-8">
      <div className="w-full flex justify-end grid my-4">
        <input className="bg-white rounded w-48 outline-0" />
      </div>
      <div className="bg-white text-red">
        <THeader>
          <THCell>Symbol</THCell>
          <THCell>Name</THCell>
          <THCell>Category</THCell>
          <THCell>Time</THCell>
        </THeader>
        <TBody></TBody>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
    }
```

Comment: please paste what you have tried so far. also a csv sample response would help a lot

Comment: Please include any code you are using! Don't forget that the first line should probably define the property names and be treated differently.

Comment: The data fetched are dynamic

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: @AXak It looks like you are battling against users who try to help you with formatting your question. I recommend deleting the post and editing it while nobody can get in your way. While you are at it, read [ask] and [mre] and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and take the [tour]. It might help you with getting your post right and with understanding why undoing helpful edits is usually not a good idea. If the question gets closed while you are eidting let me know when you are done, satisfied and convinced that the question matches the linked community rules. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @AXak you rolled back to an identical version of your post it seems. Is there any goal you are pursuing with your edits? At this point they seem random. If you explain what you try I might be able to help you.

Comment: I am pretty much confused with handling operations here tryna getting familiar with these. Sorry If anybody finds me breaking any laws here just give me a few moments until I get through handling this.

Comment: Not really "breaking laws". Just make sure that the question which got answers remains being answered by them. And still has all details which the answers were using or referring to. The current version of your post looks very much like missing most of the info. Be sure to not leave it that empty looking. I will reroll to a suitable past version now, to help you with that. When you are editing again, please make sure to refresh first and do all the editing based on the version I restore now. And keep the answers in mind and the info they used.

Comment: Note, at some point (and with my rollback we probably are already at that point) a moderator will notice this unusual editing history. I did the rollback on your feedback, to put you in a position which gives you more time for doing the right kind of editing. If you read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help you should be able to find and apply the good edit you are looking for. Good luck.

Comment: Hi AXak. I see that you remove repeatedly the CSV data and that you try to the same in the answers. If you are trying to undo the publish of sensible data, then your only chance is to flag your question for moderator attention and explain that. They can help you to make that data really become invisible. Nothing you (or even anybody with noticable more privileges, like e.g. myself) can do will achieve that. You have to flag and get help by a moderator. If you continue editing you only draw more attention to that data. It is why I asked for your goals. The data stays visible otherwise.

Comment: Your proposed edits on the answers made the data even more visible, because that asks a bunch of people to review your changes. They will read and think about the data and probably will decide that your edit is inappropriate. If anything is unclear, please ask me. Or flag. Anything else you do will just make things worse for your purpose.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a simple working example based on your CSV.

You get the header, then get the rows and use `split(',')` in order to get the data inside the rows

```js
function App() {
  let str = `Symbol,Name,Sector,Validtill
  TECHM,Tech Mahindra Ltd.,Information Technology,2022-10-27 14:04:20
  KAJARIACER,Kajaria Ceramics Ltd.,Construction,2022-10-27 14:04:20
  IDBI,IDBI Bank Ltd.,Financial Services,2022-10-27 14:04:20
  HAVELLS,Havells India Ltd.,Consumer Goods,2022-10-27 14:04:20
  SBIN,State Bank of India,Financial Services,2022-10-27 14:04:20
  IPCALAB,Ipca Laboratories Limited,,2022-10-27 14:04:20
  TORNTPOWER,Torrent Power Ltd.,Energy,2022-10-27 14:04:20
  LALPATHLAB,Dr. Lal Path Labs Ltd.,Healthcare Services,2022-10-27 14:04:20
  ENGINERSIN,Engineers India Ltd.,Construction,2022-10-27 14:04:20
  OFSS,Oracle Financial Services Software Ltd.,Information Technology,2022-10-27 14:04:20
  INFIBEAM,Infibeam Incorporation Ltd.,Information Technology,2022-10-27 14:04:20
  DIVISLAB,Divi's Laboratories Ltd.,Pharma,2022-10-27 14:04:20
  GRASIM,Grasim Industries Ltd.,Cement & Cement Products,2022-10-27 14:04:20
  ADANIPOWER,Adani Power Ltd.,Energy,2022-10-27 14:04:20
  INDIGO,InterGlobe Aviation Ltd.,Services,2022-10-27 14:04:20
  CENTURYTEX,Century Textile & Industries Ltd.,Cement & Cement Products,2022-10-27 14:04:20
  BIOCON,Biocon Ltd.,Pharma,2022-10-27 14:04:20
  AARTIIND,Aarti Industries Limited,Chemicals,2022-10-27 14:04:20
  INDUSTOWER,Indus Towers Limited ,Telecom,2022-10-27 14:04:20
  BHARATFIN,Bharat Financial Inclusion Ltd.,Financial Services,2022-10-27 14:04:20`

  const headers = str.slice(0, str.indexOf("\n")).split(',');
  const rows = str.slice(str.indexOf("\n") + 1).split("\n");

 return (
  <table className="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      {headers.map(hstr => <th key={hstr}>{hstr}</th>)}
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {rows.map(row => {
        return (
          <tr key={row}>
            {row.split(',').map(splt => <td key={splt}>{splt}</td>)}
          </tr>
        )
      })}
    </tbody>
  </table>  
 )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<html>
<div id="root"/>
</html>
```

Comment: There is more to a correctly parsed CSV then just splitting row-wise at newlines and and column-wise at any occurring comma. Especially the last guaranties for nothing for it does not cover even close the many possible formatting options of valid (and invalid) column content. It just is pure luck that the OP's example does not contain any of the more trickier possibilities like quoted column content which contains (an) additional comma/s.

Comment: Hi. You might want to double check that OPs edits do not invalidate your answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch Ops edits refer to

Answer (score -1):

Without React:

First of all, define the `table`, `thead`, `tr` and `tbody` elements. You will need utility function which in this case is fromCSVToJSON in order to transform CSV data to JSON data. Next, you need to iterate all the headers and all the contents of the data in order to create the `tr` and `td` elements.

The following code does what you're looking for:

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead><tr></tr></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

```
function fromCSVToJSON(csv) {
  const lines = csv.split('\n')
  const result = [];
  const headers = lines[0].split(',')

  for (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const obj = {}
    const currentline = lines[i].split(',')

    for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j]
    }

    result.push(obj)

  }

  return { headers: headers, contents: result }
}

const { headers, contents } = fromCSVToJSON(`Symbol,Name,Sector,Validtill
TECHM,Tech Mahindra Ltd.,Information Technology,2022-10-27 14:04:20
KAJARIACER,Kajaria Ceramics Ltd.,Construction,2022-10-27 14:04:20
IDBI,IDBI Bank Ltd.,Financial Services,2022-10-27 14:04:20
HAVELLS,Havells India Ltd.,Consumer Goods,2022-10-27 14:04:20
SBIN,State Bank of India,Financial Services,2022-10-27 14:04:20
IPCALAB,Ipca Laboratories Limited,,2022-10-27 14:04:20
TORNTPOWER,Torrent Power Ltd.,Energy,2022-10-27 14:04:20
LALPATHLAB,Dr. Lal Path Labs Ltd.,Healthcare Services,2022-10-27 14:04:20
ENGINERSIN,Engineers India Ltd.,Construction,2022-10-27 14:04:20
OFSS,Oracle Financial Services Software Ltd.,Information Technology,2022-10-27 14:04:20
INFIBEAM,Infibeam Incorporation Ltd.,Information Technology,2022-10-27 14:04:20
DIVISLAB,Divi's Laboratories Ltd.,Pharma,2022-10-27 14:04:20
GRASIM,Grasim Industries Ltd.,Cement & Cement Products,2022-10-27 14:04:20
ADANIPOWER,Adani Power Ltd.,Energy,2022-10-27 14:04:20
INDIGO,InterGlobe Aviation Ltd.,Services,2022-10-27 14:04:20
CENTURYTEX,Century Textile & Industries Ltd.,Cement & Cement Products,2022-10-27 14:04:20
BIOCON,Biocon Ltd.,Pharma,2022-10-27 14:04:20
AARTIIND,Aarti Industries Limited,Chemicals,2022-10-27 14:04:20
INDUSTOWER,Indus Towers Limited ,Telecom,2022-10-27 14:04:20
BHARATFIN,Bharat Financial Inclusion Ltd.,Financial Services,2022-10-27 14:04:20`)

const table = document.getElementById('table')
const headTR = table.querySelector('thead > tr')

for (const header of headers) {
  const headTD = document.createElement('td')
  headTD.textContent = header
  headTR.append(headTD)
}

for (const content of contents) {
  const bodyTR = document.createElement('tr')
  for (const header of headers) {
    const bodyTD = document.createElement('td')
    bodyTD.textContent = content[header]
    bodyTR.append(bodyTD)
  }
  document.body.append(bodyTR)
}
```

Comment: Hi. You might want to double check that OPs edits do not invalidate your answer.